# Por que botões de video nao funcionam em navegadores após usar css?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que exibe um video no site com NodeJS, socket io, express.

Somente tem 1 página com a tag `<video>`.

Quero que o video ao clicar em play fique em tela cheia, porém isso nao acontece entao usei esse css que peguei da internet para o video ocupar 100% do navegador:

```html
<style>
video#V1 { 
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
</style>

<body>
  <video  id="V1" controls>
  <source src="Videos/a.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="Videos/a.webm" type="video/webm" />  
  </video>
</body>
```

E com isso descobri que o botão de 'play' ou qualquer outro do video só funciona no Firefox. Já tentei com Chrome, Edge, Opera e nenhum desses o botao 'play' funciona.

Ao remover o css, o botão 'play' funciona normalmente em qualquer navegador...

Alguém poderia me explicar o por que?

Comment: É dificil ajudar sem ver o HTML... podes colocar isso na pergunta? Testa tirar o `z-index: -100;`, pode ser que algum elemento esteja a tapar...

Comment: Coloquei o código do html, é só o body e o video mesmo...

Tentei o que disse de tirar o z-index e funcionou, obrigado!!

Sabem me dizer como deixar em tela cheia ao clicar no 'play'?

Vlw

Comment: Vê na consola, na aba network, se o url está certo. Como tens `Videos` com letra grande pode ser esse o problema.

Comment: Já agora podes criar um jsFiddle com um exemplo a funcionar que tenha bug?

Comment: O botão só funciona no Firefox ou sua tela que não mostra o botão dos demais navegadores? [Olhe este exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/NpgD5/1189/) e arraste altere o `max-width` para outros valores. Navegadores como Chrome e Edge não possuem botão de play no centro da tela. Geralmente, somente no canto inferior direito. Todavia, altere o Fiddle com o seu exemplo como disse o @Sergio que será mais fácil lhe ajudar. :p

Comment: @Randrade - Os botões de controle aparecem em todos os navegadores sim. 
Estou usando isso com NODEJs para testar o video rodar em diversos browsers ao mesmo tempo, sincronizado. por isso estou abrindo o site até em celular.